# Ejecting from Expo

Tags: expo

I have to eject from expo in my react native project, but I still want to maintain some functionalities provided by their libraries, like notifications. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I equally want to eject from expo now. Is there any error / difficulty that you encountered after ejecting from expo??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with **SDK33 Expo** was changed to install its own modules separately as required. If you have installed and used the `notification` module using `expo install`, you can use it normally even with an `eject`.

Check whether a module is available on `MainApplication.java` for Android or `info.list` for ios.